# How to extract an integer from end of the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, parseint

How can we extract integer (keys) from such a data set ?

```
data : {
    DAYS7: 234,
    DAYS21: 3456,
    DAYS35: 23456
}
```

I want to convert this data into two arrays `[7, 21, 35]` and `[234, 3456, 23456]`.

Code:

```
var a = [], b = [];
for (var key in data) {
  a.push(getIntPart(key));
  b.push(data[key]);
}

function getIntPart(key) {
  key = key.substring(4); //Remove DAYS word
  return parseInt(key);
}
```

I think `key.substring(4)` is not the right way to do it because it will fail for some other key. Please suggest how should I solve this issue.

Comment: You're missing a `)` on that first `push` btw.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for telling me the typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
key = (key.match(/\d+$/) || []).pop();
```

This will match all numbers (`\d+`) at the end (`$`) of `key` string.

Comment: Oh right..Why didn't I think of this..Thanks a lot..I think it will do.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only every "DAYS" you need to remove use a simple `replace`:

```
a.push(+k.replace('DAYS', ''));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/8gXdE/)

Or, using your example:

```
function getIntPart(key) {
  key = key.replace('DAYS', '');
  return parseInt(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use split here and extract the second token:

```
key = key.split(/(\d+)/)[1]
```